# Does entities sharing the same parent entities share relationship instead of just attributes?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4

Say I have entity

```
Businesses
Reviews
Reviewers
```

Each entity has a member called rating.

So I add another entity called

```
Rateable
```

with property Rating

And make it a parent for all 3

Now all Businesses, Reviews and Reviewers will automatically have a property called Rating right?

Now what about if Rating it self is not an attribute but a relationship.

Will Businesses, Reviews and Reviewers have a relationship called Rating too? Also what would be the inverse relationship of Rating then?

Now, say I want to turn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, relationships can be inherited. The reverse of rating would need to be created for the superclass so it would be between Rating and Rateable. Subclasses would inherit this as well.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH Great insight